# Angular2 - detect typos in templates

Tags: debugging, angular2-template, string-interpolation, misspelling

What is best way to detect typos in HTML templates?

Example:

```
<h1>{{computer.systemTye}}</h1>
```

should be

```
<h1>{{computer.systemType}}</h1>
```

Ideally, I'd like to see the error in console during compilation. Or in debug console in browser.

I know I can write unit tests using `TestBed` class and use something like this

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
el = de.nativeElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the default operator to show an error message. For example:

```
{{nae || 'error'}}
```

**References**

- [setting a default value to an undefined variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409813/setting-a-default-value-to-an-undefined-variable-in-javascript)
- [Default value of a type in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603106/default-value-of-a-type-in-javascript)